# Generating .xsd from C# class file, then generate class from the .xsd file it generated

Tags: c#, xsd

We lost all .xsd files, only have C# classes files left. I'm using xsd.exe to generate .xsd files from C# classes files, but when I use xsd.exe to generate back C# classes from these generated .xsd files, new C# class files are different from the original ones.

In order to illustrate my problem, I simplified code as below:

VisualStuio 2008

Project name: web, project type: C# Class Library

Build output: web.dll

2 source files:

File #1: Response.cs  (contains base class)

```
    namespace VWS.Types
{
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Response
    {

    }

}
```

File #2: ResponseTSIRetrieveList.cs

```
    namespace VWS.Types
{
    using System.Xml.Serialization;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class ResponseTSIRetrieveList : Response
    {


    }
}
```

Step 1: Generate .xsd file from ResponseTSIRetrieveList class:

```
       xsd.exe -t:ResponseTSIRetrieveList web.dll

      schema0.xsd file is generated.
```

Step2: Generate C# class from the .xsd file:

```
    xsd.exe -c schema0.xsd
```

Here is the generated C# file:

```
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.1432.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=true)]
public partial class ResponseTSIRetrieveList : Response {
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ResponseTSIRetrieveList))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.1432")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class Response {
}
```

As you can see, both base class and derived class are generated in same file. How can I avoid this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Are you sure in the original code this was not manually separated? Typically xsd generates all classes in one file. Also seeign that the `XmlRootAttribute`s were commented out, the original code looks like it was modified after generation (bad practice in any case)

Comment: Thanks for your comment zaitsman.